# Iterate over byte vector and save pointers to strings

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<u8>` which contains UTF-8 strings that are separated by `'\0' as u8`. Fixed length binary packed data is placed after each string, like this:

`b"abc\0" 10_bytes_of_data b"ufhd\0" 10_bytes_data`,

I want to parse such a `Vec<u8>` and fill a `Vec<&str>`. To simplify things I replace `10_bytes_of_data` with `0_bytes_of_data`:

```
let cnt = b"abc\0efg\0";
let mut cnt_vec = Vec::<u8>::new();
for ch in cnt {
    cnt_vec.push(*ch);
}
let mut str_start_it = cnt_vec.iter();
let mut strings = Vec::<&str>::new();
let mut cur_it = cnt_vec.iter();
let mut counter: usize = 0;
loop {
    match cur_it.next() {
        Some(ch) => {
            if *ch == 0u8 {
                {
                    let slice = str_start_it.as_slice();
                    let s = std::str::from_utf8(&slice[0..counter]).unwrap();
                    strings.push(s);
                }
                str_start_it = cur_it.clone();
                counter = 0;
            } else {
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        None => {
            break;
        }
    }
}

for s in strings {
    println!("s {}", s);
}
```

and I have several questions:

1. Is there any simpler way to convert `cnt` to `cnt_vec`?
2. Is it possible to write the main algorithm in fewer lines of code? In the real world I have 10 bytes between strings; I plan to use `Iterator::nth`.
3. Is there any unnecessary heap allocation in my code? I want to have heap allocations only in `cnt_vec` and `strings`, maybe some lines except `push` allocate memory on the heap?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do this (with support for ignoring a fixed number of extra data like you want):

```
fn main() {
    const DATA_LEN: usize = 3;
    let bytes = b"abc\0zzzefg\0zzzhij\0zzz".to_vec();
    let mut strs = Vec::new();
    for (i, chunk) in bytes.split(|&b| b == b'\0').enumerate() {
        // The first chunk doesn't have the extra data at the start.
        let skip = if i == 0 {
            0
        } else {
            DATA_LEN
        };
        strs.push(std::str::from_utf8(&chunk[skip..]).unwrap());
    }
    // Remove the last str. If the data is valid, it should be empty as the last
    // chunk only contains extra data.
    strs.pop();
    for str in strs {
        println!("{}", str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc
efg
hij
```

The only heap allocation (after `bytes`) here is `strs`, which will use about `2 words * number of strs` of heap memory.

Edit: More functional version (no `mut`!), but this would also skip all 0 sized strings:

```
fn main() {
    const DATA_LEN: usize = 3;
    let bytes = b"abc\0zzzefg\0zzzhij\0zzz".to_vec();
    let strs = bytes.split(|&b| b == b'\0')
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(i, chunk)| {
            // The first chunk doesn't have the extra data at the start.
            let skip = if i == 0 {
                0
            } else {
                DATA_LEN
            };
            if skip == chunk.len() {
                None
            } else {
                Some(std::str::from_utf8(&chunk[skip..]).unwrap())
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    for str in strs {
        println!("{}", str);
    }
}
```

I would use this if your data will not have empty strings. This should run just as fast as the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your own iterator:

```
struct DataSplitter<'d> {
    data: &'d [u8],
    pos: usize,
    dlen: usize,
}

impl<'d> DataSplitter<'d> {
    fn new(data: &'d [u8], dlen: usize) -> DataSplitter {
        DataSplitter {
            data: data,
            pos: 0,
            dlen: dlen,
        }
    }
}

impl<'d> Iterator for DataSplitter<'d> {
    type Item = &'d [u8];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'d [u8]> {
        if self.pos < self.data.len() {
            if let Some(zpos) = self.data[self.pos..].iter().position(|&x| x == 0) {
                // zero found. prepare slice
                let res = &self.data[self.pos..self.pos + zpos];
                // move current position
                self.pos += zpos + self.dlen + 1;
                Some(res)
            } else {
                // No more zeros found. Return all bytes
                let res = &self.data[self.pos..];
                self.pos = self.data.len();
                Some(res)//You can return None if you want skip it
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    const DLEN: usize = 2;
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = b"abc\0\x01\0zxc\0\t\x02fgh\0\x01\n".to_vec();

    let res = DataSplitter::new(&bytes, DLEN)
        .map(|s| std::str::from_utf8(s))
        .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()
        .expect("UTF8 error");

    println!("{:?}", res);//["abc", "zxc", "fgh"]
}
```

Comment: what if `fixed length packed data` between utf-8 strings contains b'\0'?

Comment: Everything goes wrong. I had not foreseen this case

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users), as your code works but you are looking for a better solution.

The only allocation you need is for the vector to hold the strings. Beyond that, you can use the input slice as the backing memory.

```
const PADDING_LENGTH: usize = 1;

use std::str;

fn main() {
    let cnt = b"abc\0\x01efg\0\x01";

    let mut a = cnt as &[u8];
    let mut words = vec![];

    while let Some(idx) = a.iter().position(|&x| x == b'\0') {
        let (head, tail) = a.split_at(idx);
        let word = str::from_utf8(head).expect("Invalid UTF-8");
        words.push(word);

        // +1 to skip over the NUL
        if tail.len() > PADDING_LENGTH + 1 {
            a = &tail[PADDING_LENGTH + 1..];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    assert_eq!(words, ["abc", "efg"]);
}
```

There's no need to convert the input slice to a `Vec`, but the better way of doing it would be [`to_vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec%60):

```
fn main() {
    let cnt = b"abc\0efg\0";
    let mut cnt_vec = Vec::<u8>::new();
    for ch in cnt {
        cnt_vec.push(*ch);
    }

    let cnt_vec_better = cnt.to_vec();
    assert_eq!(cnt_vec, cnt_vec_better)
}
```

It's better to use `b'0'` to indicate a single-byte literal; it's the mirror of `b""` for multi-byte literals.

Comment: Thanks, I have been using rust only last two days, so I need not "code review", but  "code rewrite", as you demonstrate.

Comment: @user1034749 check out the [code reviews for Rust](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rust); many of them have the same amount of "check out this standard library function or crate you didn't know about" or "you are allocating too much memory here". The code reviews over there are very thorough, and often involve rewriting large chunks. Code review isn't limited to "are my variable names good".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the regex crate:

```
extern crate regex;

fn main() {
    let data = b"abc\0123456789xfu\nhd\0123456789x";
    let re = regex::bytes::Regex::new(r"(?s)(.*?)\0.{10}").unwrap();
    let v: Vec<&str> = re.captures_iter(data)
        .map(|captures| std::str::from_utf8(captures.at(1).unwrap()).unwrap())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

The `s` flag is quite important here, without it the `.` won't match newline and consecutive strings might end up being not consecutive.

If you care about performance of this code, please note that each `Captures` will allocate a `Vec`. You can get rid of this allocation by using `find_iter` instead and slicing the last 11 bytes off manually.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write the main algorithm in fewer lines of code? In the real world I have 10 bytes between strings; I plan to use `Iterator::nth`.

Here is another option:

```
fn main() {
    let bytes = b"abc\0???efg\0???hij\0".to_vec();
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    let mut chunks = bytes.split(|&b| b == b'\0');
    if let Some(first) = chunks.next().map(from_utf8_unwrap) {
        v.push(first);
        v.extend(chunks.map(skip_data).map(from_utf8_unwrap));
        v.pop(); // discard the last string
    }
    assert_eq!(vec!["abc", "efg", "hij"], v);
}

const PADDING: usize = 3;

fn skip_data(s: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
    &s[std::cmp::min(s.len(), PADDING)..]
}

fn from_utf8_unwrap(s: &[u8]) -> &str {
    std::str::from_utf8(s).unwrap()
}
```